# Execution of xpath failed in Mulesoft

Tags: xpath, mule, mule-studio

My Mulesoft process is making a call to SuccessFactors API. The /LOGIN call results in a response like this.

```
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <S:Body>
          <loginResponse xmlns="urn:sfobject.sfapi.successfactors.com" xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.sfapi.successfactors.com">
             <result>
                <sessionId>9A95*******A2631B8E820894CA.ps8bsfapi52t</sessionId>
                <msUntilPwdExpiration>9223372036854775807</msUntilPwdExpiration>
             </result>
          </loginResponse>
       </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

I've the following name spaces declared in my namespace manager

```
            <mulexml:namespace-manager>
                <mulexml:namespace prefix="S" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                <mulexml:namespace prefix="ns2" uri="urn:fault.sfapi.successfactors.com"/>
                <mulexml:namespace prefix="" uri="urn:sfobject.sfapi.successfactors.com"/>
            </mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

I want to read the sessionId into a mule session variable.

```
    <set-session-variable variableName="SESSION" value="#[xpath('//S:Envelope/S:Body/loginResponse/result/sessionId').text]" doc:name="Get Session from Login"/>
```

But, upon execution I end up in this

```
        <faultstring>Execution of the expression "xpath('//S:Envelope/S:Body/loginResponse/result/sessionId').text" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).</faultstring>
```

The XPath checks out well on any other tool but for Mulesoft.

Comment: Thanks. But that's something the successfactors system responds with. I can't change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XPATH with `*` as namespace, so you dont need to bother about namespace.

```
#[xpath('//*:Envelope/*:Body/*:loginResponse/*:result/*:sessionId').text]
```

xpath is deprecated new version of mule.

**Update:**

```
#[xpath3('//*:Envelope/*:Body/*:loginResponse/*:result/*:sessionId')]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But no, that didn't work. The result is the same.

Comment: Please check updated answer. Use `xpath3` instead `xpath`. It worked for me.

Comment: Well, that was a bit premature. It doesn't dump any more. But it doesn't fetch the variable
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="query" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="SESSION" value="#[xpath3('//*:Envelope/*:Body/*:loginResponse/result/sessionId')]" doc:name="Get Session from Login"/>
        <logger message="session is: #[sessionVars.SESSION]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logging"/>

Comment: INFO  2017-12-05 12:06:45,254 [[pilatus].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: session is:  


Session is empty

Comment: got it
#[xpath3('//*:sessionId',payload,'STRING')]".
That was in one of your other answers.